# running rpush as daemon in production using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification, capistrano

I have set up my rails app for use with rpush. It works fine locally in development using `rpush start`. But now I want to deploy it to my EC2 server using capistrano-**2.15.5**.

Part of my `deploy.rb`:

```
after "deploy:stop",    "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:stop",    "rpush:stop"

after "deploy:start",   "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:start",   "rpush:start"

after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"
after "deploy:restart", "rpush:restart"

namespace :rpush do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} rpush deamon"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec rpush #{command}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now, the problems

- it starts in development environment. I tried to understand [this](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/issues/66) page that tells me how to do it, but I could not.
- I do not know whether the pid is stored in the `/current` dir or `/shared` dir. It should be in the shared so that the file persists between deploys

If anyone has done this (even in a different way) please tell me how to.

Or, how can I fix my cap recipe and `/initializers/rpush`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Capistrano 3:

```
after :finished, :restart_rpush do
  on roles(:web) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush stop -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"
        execute :bundle, :exec, "rpush start -e #{fetch(:rails_env)}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then check that `tmp` and other directories is linked correctly:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/uploads}
```

Comment: Sorry @maxd, forgot to mention I am using capistrano-2. But I understood what you wrote. I will append `-e #{fetch(:rails_env)}` .
Also, I wanted to have it as a different namespace so that I can do `cap rpush:start`